# Angularjs: Expected `2015-11-21T02:00:00.000Z` to be a date

Tags: angularjs, node.js, date

I am developing an application MEAN with tasks and projects. But when I edit the due date of a task I receive this error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-11-21T02:00:00.000Z` to be a date
```

I already researched a lot about it, and I could not make any of the solutions to solve my problem, please help me!

My html input to the delivery date is this:

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="task.deadline" id="deadline" required>
```

This is my client-side controller (angular):

```
// Find a task by the id
$scope.findOne = function() {
  $scope.task = Tasks.get({
    taskId: $routeParams.taskId
  });
};
```

This is my server-side controller (node):

```
// Find a specific task using the id
exports.taskByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
  Task.findById(id).populate('creator', 'firstName lastName fullName').exec(function(err, task) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!task) return next(new Error('Não foi possível carregar a tarefa ' + id));
    req.task = task;
    task.deadline = new Date(task.deadline);
    next();
  });
};
```

Someone help me!

Comment: Try on catching date parse it as new Date()

Comment: I'm a total noob in MEAN :( I have to do that on server-side?

Comment: After getting data and before assignment you need to convert data to what you need, some kind of transformer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Tasks` is a `$resource` object you'll need to add a `transformResponse` interceptor like :

```
var Tasks = $resource('/service/server/method', {}, {
  get: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: false,
    transformResponse: function(data, header) {
      var obj = angular.fromJson(data);
      obj.deadline = new Date(data.deadline)
      // you will want to use moment.js to handle your dates on the clientside if you expect any kind of timezone accuracy.
      return obj;
    }
  }
```